# Design pattern for multiple buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the better way to do this (the more buttons the longer the code is getting)?

Does one have to add to an array (then use reflection to look at the variable title and pull out the proper string?

```
//Load defaults
    _n1From = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_N1_FROM_UD];
    _n1To = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_N1_TO_UD];
    _n2From = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_N2_FROM_UD];
    _n2To = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_N2_TO_UD];
    _unionRate = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_UNION_RATE_UD];
    _unionHours = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_UNION_HOURS_UD];
    _nonUnionRate = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_NON_UNION_RATE_UD];
    _nonUnionHours = [HelperMethods getObjectUserDefault:AS_NON_UNION_HOURS_UD];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put buttons into `IBOutletCollection`, assign each button a unique `tag` value, and then use the tag to look up the argument in an `NSArray` that mapps the tag to the parameter. Here is an example:

```
NSArray *tagToArg = @[@AS_N1_FROM_UD, @AS_N1_TO_UD, @AS_N2_FROM_UD, ...];
for (UIButton *b in allButtonsOutletCollection) {
    [HelperMethods configureButton:b withData:tagToArg[b.tag]];
}
```

The button with the tag zero will get the argument `AS_N1_FROM_UD`; the button with the tag `1` will get `AS_N1_TO_UD`, and so on.